# how to insert text on image using java script in nopcommerce

Tags: javascript, nopcommerce

Hi im using nopcommerce 2.60 (MVC structure), how to insert text on image using javascript

thank you

Answer (score 1):

If you want embed text onto the image. You can't do that with javascript unless you are using html5's [SVG](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-scalable/index.html).